# How to handle null data from store in vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently I am receiving error if one of the data is null. The data get it from the vuex store. How can I remove the error?

```
data (){
    return{
      projects: this.$store.state.authUser.roles
    }
  },
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? Are you certain you set `authUser` and `authUser.roles` before the snippet above?

Comment: You need to add code to deal with the situation when `authUser` is null, your code assumes that it won't ever be null.

Comment: Can you provide more details to your problem? This is way too generic to figure out anything

Answer (score 0):

it is not good practice to use ***this*** instance before ***created()*** hook like ***data()*** block, so set the value after after or into created hook like below

```
data (){
    return{
      projects: null
    }
  },
created(){
this. projects =this.$store.state.authUser.roles
}
```

N.B: and it is better to get store data using getters

```
this.$store.getters.AUTH_USER_ROLES


const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    authUser: {
roles:[]
}
  },
  getters: {
    AUTH_USER_ROLES: state => state.authUser.roles,
  }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

like this?

```
data (){
  return{
    projects: this.$store.state.authUser && this.$store.state.authUser.roles
  }
},
```